# Python and VS Code, messy paths in terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

I've just started with Python, I've installed Python and it's extension from Microsoft, and when I run Python file in terminal I get the results, but the ugly path is covering plenty of space in terminal (like on the photo below). I've found video how to remove that from debbuging console, but couldn't find anything related to normal terminal. Is there any solution for that?
I am using Windows 10 and newest version of VS Code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjKOm.png

Comment: I think that's a regular `cmd.exe` output. You can change the prompt using the settings shown in these docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/prompt

Answer (score 1):

You need to do 3 things.

1.

You need to add Python to your PATH. Call this python2 if you want to use python 3 as well for other project.

(However if you are starting, considering using python 3 from the beginning)

2.

Just use the file name if you are already in the folder

Your command is reduced to this then:

```
python2 strings.py
```

3.

Use prompt to change the line before your command. See doc for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/prompt

Comment: It helped a bit, however the prompt line is changed there is still remaining some path and I have no idea where does it come from. And it works only when i manually run .py file from VS Code, beacuse when i enter path it just opens file with external console window and immediately closing it

https://files.fm/thumb_show.php?i=z9qw5f38&view

Comment: The part that you marked in the last screenshot can be replaced by using PATH. Change your enviroment variables. I don't get you completely though. What do you mean 'when i enter path'? Documentation for PATH: https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/

Comment: By 'when i enter path' I ment that I type in name of my file in the terminal, for example strings.py in the command line. 
I added to PATH few directories, a python.exe location, folder with my files I work with and it didn't help. I also reinstalled whole Python, using an "Add to PATH" option while installing it. No idea what else should I put in path to make it work.

https://i.ibb.co/CwkyQHd/Bez-tytu-u.png
@EDIT
Okay I figured that when i type my file name it works. So I guess that is fixed, but it doesn't show results in terminal, only flashes console